# Does [UIView transitionWithView:...] happen off the main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've been working on optimizing scrolling performance (f.p.s.) of an image heavy news feed table view.

I noticed that when I added in the following, which I expected would slow things down, performance actually *felt* better, i.e. less stuttering.

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:self
                      duration:0.3f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^{ self.image = image; }
                    completion:NULL];
```

I'm willing to believe that the cross dissolve effect gives the illusion of smoother scrolling, but I'd also buy it that the animation/drawing is being dispatched off of the main thread (is that even possible), freeing up the UI to focus on the other aspects of scrolling minus drawing the image on the canvas.

So what gives, am I imagining things?

It's difficult to profile Core Animation for scrolling since it's dependent on network (images are URL based), scroll speed, velocity etc. so this is a purely anecdotal observation. Any recommendation for doing some more consistent scrolling profiling would be welcomed.

UIView [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:) for reference.